# What is the valid value for destinationTable for the Data Factory Diagnostic settings in the ARM JSON Tempate?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to use the recommended Diagnostic Settings for Azure Data Factory using "Resource Specific" destination table. I'm using ARM Templates to deploy the change, but none of the values I put in seems to work:

What is the correct value to use "resource specific" destination table?

Thanks!

I have tried these different values in the ARM Template: resourceSpecific, ResourceSpecific, Resource-Specific

```
 "properties": {
            "name": "[variables('LogAnalyticsSettingName')]",
            "storageAccountId": null,
            "eventHubAuthorizationRuleId": null,
            "eventHubName": null,
            "workspaceId": "[resourceId('microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces',parameters('OMSWorkspaceName'))]",
            "destinationTable": "resourceSpecific",
            "logs": [
              {
                "category": "PipelineRuns",
                "enabled": true,
                "retentionPolicy": {
                  "enabled": false,
                  "days": 0
                }
              }
```

After deploying the ARM Template...
Expected Result: Destination table is Resource Specific in the ADF Diagnostics Settings

Actual Result: Destination table remains to be Azure diagnostics

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find the solution by reviewing the Activity Log in the Data Factory when I change the diagnostic settings manually from the portal.

In the "Create or update resource diagnostic setting" JSON request body, I saw a property called "logAnalyticsDestinationType" with a value of "Dedicated".

I removed the destinationTable property in the ARM JSON template and replaced it with "logAnalyticsDestinationType":"Dedicated" instead and redeployed the ARM template. It worked as expected.